# Benefits of using CSS modules with React/Vue

Tags: css, reactjs, vue.js, css-modules

I would like to understand the benefits of using **CSS Modules** with **React**/**Vue**.

Currently in my company developers use the following in development:

```
return (
    <div className={styles.User}>
        <div className={styles.name}>...</div>
    </div>
)
```

While using a **CSS module** file, something like:

```scss
.User {
    background-color: var(--bg-color, red);

    .name { color: white; }
}
```

What should an HTML output such as:

```html
<div class="_User_xyz_1">
    <div class="_name_abc_1">...</div>
</div>
```

Which is a bit confusing for me, as this "*encodes*" all the class names and creates a great deal of difficulty if I need to do a **parent-level modification**. Eg.:

```html
<div class="SomeParent">
    <User name="David" />
</div>
```

So:

```css
.SomeParent {
    > .User {
        --bg-color: blue; // Will not words, because .User is not .User, in fact.
    }
}
```

In personal projects, I prefer to name the **primary element** of the template by defining it as a "major class", the main. Eg.:

```
return (
    <div className="User">
        <div className="name">...</div>
    </div>
)
```

And a **regular CSS/SCSS**:

```scss
.User {
    background-color: var(--bg-color, red);

    > .name { color: white; }
}
```

So a parent element's code can affect a child element under expected and controlled conditions.

**My question here is:** what are the **benefits** of using the model that my company uses that I am not able to see? Am I missing something using a more "*moderate/primitive*" model?

**Another possibility is:** can I modify the style of child elements through the parent element, even with the name of the classes being encoded this way?

Answer (score 1):

CSS modules generate custom classnames for each style and therefore prevent the problem you are facing in your solution. Because each css module style has its own classname you cannot accidentially change a child components style.

Comment: Changing the child to the parent is expected. I need to (eg.) change the `background-color` according to "who uses it" (the parent who uses it, in this case). So the problem cited is actually something I need to be that way. Hence the general doubt. In the model via CSS Modules I need to do some "workarounds".

Comment: But this is an anti pattern. Components are self containing units and you should only access the most outer element of your component. Nonetheless you can still hack your way around by doing something like `className={styles.User + " my-custom-class"}`

Comment: @CodeSpirit what is the benefit of using a CSS Module (class hashed) versus simply using a scoped style _(Vue e.g. `<style scoped> your classes </style>`)_? The only benefit I can see so far is: selectors with `[ATTR]` are "slower" than plain hashed classes. But this is like, super micro-performance gain, not that important nowadays. The child will still be safeguarded from parent styles, as all parent selectors are attr selectors too, e.g `.someclass[data-v-somehash]`.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL I didnt know `<style scoped>` is a thing... My answer is mostly related to ReactJS because I dont have any experience with vue. I dont see a difference there.

Answer (score 1):

hash className, preventing other developers from quickly decompiling your style scheme.

Answer (score 0):

SCSS module styles are applied by very unique classes thanks to the hash, and therefore have no real risk of unintended style collisions. This allows you to use short, meaningful class names without having to think of any global styles you might be colliding with. You can confidently style without fear of breaking things elsewhere in your application.

You could, in theory, add generic class names which are not applied via your scss modules to give your parent component a class name with which to work.

Comment: I'm currently adding class names "by hand" like you quoted in the second paragraph, but this seems pretty hacky to me for something that should solve problems.

Comment: Look into 'compose'... I'm not super familiar with the concept but you may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the React components should be as modular and generic as possible. I think the way to go is such that types are exported from one component. Styles should be inline or at the bottom at a styles object.

Comment: Also consider a theme provider HOC.